# Sort results by name & asc order on homepage

Tags: functions

When I insert this code in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_change_sort_order'); 
function my_change_sort_order($query){
    if(is_post_type_archive()):
     //If you wanted it for the archive of a custom post type use: is_post_type_archive( $post_type )
       //Set the order ASC or DESC
       $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
       //Set the orderby
       $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
    endif;    
};
```

sorting occurs throughout the site, I just need to on the main page in which the ID 540. Tried options with

```
if(is_post_type_archive() && is_page('540')):
```

and

```
if(is_post_type_archive() && is_home()):
```

and

```
if(is_post_type_archive() && is_front_page()):
```

all not working.
please help anybody, thanks!

Comment: The main (home / front) page is not a post type archive page. So why are you using this condition?

Comment: because it displays the properties in the form of archives on my website

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to hook into the posts on your homepage, I think you only need something like this:

```
<?php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_change_sort_order'); 
function my_change_sort_order( $query ){

   if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) :

      if ( is_front_page() ) :
         //Set the order ASC or DESC
         $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
         //Set the orderby
         $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
      endif;

   endif;
}
?>
```

Comment: not working for me :(

Comment: "Did you get the same 404 page?"
 -No.

Comment: What was the outcome then?

Answer (score -1):

Its working for me. Thx for help!

```
 add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_change_sort_order'); 
    function my_change_sort_order( $query ){

       if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) :

          if ( is_archive() ) :
             //Set the order ASC or DESC
             $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
             //Set the orderby
             $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
          endif;

       endif;
    }
```

Comment: Nope, I changed it "if ( is_front_page() ) :"
 to this "if ( is_archive() ) :"